# How to test component with named slots in cypress and vue3?

Tags: cypress, vuejs3

I have a component which has a list of buttons and the buttons are rendered with slots. The button is another component, not the native `<button>` tag. How should I mount the buttons in a cypress test for Comment component?

```
Comment.vue
<template>
  <slot #buttons></slot>
</template>
```

```
Button.vue
<template>
  <button></button>
</template>
```

For the sake of simplicity I simplified the examples.

Answer (score 0):

> I got you, see the example

```
// Comment.vue
<template>
  <slot #buttons></slot>
</template>
```

```
// Button.vue
<template>
  <button>click me</button>
</template>
```

```
// App.vue
<template>
     <CommentVue #buttons> <ButtonVue/> </CommentVue>
</template>
<script setup>
import ButtonVue from './Button.vue'
import CommentVue from './Comment.vue'
</script>
```

Comment: What I want is to test the Comment component in Cypress. And I don't know how to mount the component together with slots.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).